# Is the JDBC Connection Pool Size to low in web Application?

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I have a Web Application with tomcat, JSP , Java and MS SQL Database.

I have written a Connection Pool for the JDBC Connections.

The user in our web application are higher since one month. Now we have the problem that sometimes, a request, which need also database values , slow down or delay.

In the Code I have seen a Connection `pool_size`. The value of the `pool_size` is 10.

So I think it could be maximum 10 Database connection in the pool, but i'm not sure.

So my question is, if its possible that the delay and slow down could happen because the `pool_size` is to low ?

Comment: It is a possibility, but I'd rather suspect the queries involved. Easy to test of course: increase the pool size and see if that changes anything!

Comment: You should be able to monitor the connection pool I suppose. Check if is fully consumed at some point.